# Exercises of the type $||Tx|| \ge \alpha ||x||$ if or only if ...

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have three following assignments in Functional Analysis Course which are given after chapter 3 of Conway's Functional Analysis book but there is no section I could find that is related, neither could I find in the Internet. **Based on which theorems** I can start solving them? because I think they are irrelevant to the chapter?

I. Let X be a Bananch space, Y be a normed space and $T \in \mathcal{B}(X,y)$. If there exists $\alpha>0$ such that for all $x \in X$, $||Tx|| \ge \alpha ||x||$ then $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ is closed.

II. If $X$ and $Y$ are normed linear spaces and $\mathcal{B}(X,y)$ be invertible then for all $x \in X$,  $||Tx|| \ge ||T^{-1}||^{-1} ||x||$.

III. Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $T \in \mathcal{B}(X,y)$. Then the two following are equivalent : a) $T$ is invertible. b) $\operatorname{ran}(T)$ is dense in $Y$ and there is an $\alpha>0$ such that for all $x \in X$, $||Tx|| \ge \alpha ||x||$.

Comment: They require no theorems besides the basic definitions of a Banach space

Comment: @SolubleFish, can you please give some small hints so I can start them? Thanks

Comment: For I and II, just apply the definitions : for I, take a sequence in $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ converging in $Y$ and show its limit is in $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ ; for II, use $x = T^{-1} T x$ and the properties of the operator norms. The last point is a combination of $I$ and $II$

Comment: @L.G. The first property is called boundedness from below, and is equivalent to the property of being topologically injective. The second one is similar to the first. The third follows from the previous two.

Comment: I will try. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. let $(y_n)$ be a sequence in $\operatorname{Im}(T)$, converging to $y\in Y$. There is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $Tx_n = y_n$. Then, we have :
   $$\|x_n - x_m\| \leq \alpha^{-1}\|T(x_n-x_m)\|  = \alpha^{-1}\|y_n -y_m\|$$
   This means that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, and therefore converges to $x\in X$. Since $T$ is continuous and $y_n=Tx_n$, we get $y = Tx \in \operatorname{Im}(T)$. We conclude that $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ is closed.
2. Assume $T$ is invertible and $x\in X$. Then, we have $x = T^{-1} Tx$ and therefore : $$\|x\| = \|T^{-1}Tx\|\leq\|T^{-1}\|\|Tx\|$$
3. If $T$ is invertible, that by 2. $T$ is bounded from below and its range is $Y$ (which is dense). If the range of $T$ is dense and bounded from below. Then by $1.$, the range of $T$ is closed, and therefore is equal to $Y$. Boundedness from below then implies that $T$ is injective (and therefore a continuous bijection), and that $T^{-1}$ is bounded.

---

**Edit** : More details on the last point

There is $\alpha >0$ such that $\| Tx\| \geq \alpha\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$. In particular, if $x\in X$ is such that $Tx = 0$, we have :
$$\| x \|\leq \alpha^{-1} \|Tx\|=0$$
Therefore $T$ is injective.

We now know that $T$ is a bounded linear bijection. It remains to show that $T^{-1}$ is bounded. For all $x\in X$, we have :
$$\|T^{-1} x\| \leq \alpha^{-1}\|TT^{-1}x\| = \alpha^{-1}\|x\|$$
ie $T^{-1}$ is bounded.

Comment: A typo, $\|x_n - x_m\| \leq \alpha\|T(x_n-x_m)\|  = \alpha\|y_n -y_m\|$ it should be $\alpha^{-1}$?

Comment: I don't understand Q3: 1- T invertible implies T is onto (by definition or proof?)? 2- How boundedness from below then implies that T is injective? 3- T bounded from above implies continuous how you say from below too? 4- Finally, how T^{−1} is bounded you concluded? 5- How T^{−1} is bounded implies T is invertible?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you please answer all 5 questions because each is impenetrable for me! Thanks :)

Comment: @L.G. 1- Do you know what invertible means (this is standard)? 2- If $T$ is bounded below, then when is $T(x) =0$? 3- If $T$ is bounded above, then what can you say about $\|T(x)-T(y)\|$? 4-This follows after you understand 3. 5- Clearly, there is confusion here. The fact that you wrote $T^{-1}$ already means $T$ is invertible.

Comment: @solublefish all my 5 questions were because of last sentence "Boundedness from below then implies that T is injective (and therefore a continuous bijection), and that T^−1 is bounded" can you please explain this better  I am still in confusion

Comment: Thanks a lot :)